# How do I use jq to filter an array that contains both objects and strings?

Tags: json, jq

So I have this input to jq:

```
[
  "foo",
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 3
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

and I want to select all objects where b is 2 ideally as an array:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

But the string in the list makes that difficult.

If I try:

`.[]| select(.b == 2)`

Then I get the error:

`jq: error (at /tmp/data.json:14): Cannot index string with string "b"`

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have suggested using `?` which is very good. Another way is to use the built-in `objects` filter which discards an input if it is not an object:

```
map(objects | select(.b == 2))
#   ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#   A         B
```

A: filter out non-objects
B: At this point, we're dealing with objects

Slightly more verbose and perhaps less efficient?

Comment: Probably no less efficient, and the verbosity clarifies intent, so I would call this a perfectly good option.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options.

---

Ignore errors using `?`:

```
map(select(.b? == 2))
```

[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#OptionalObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo?), [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/7WadUwNDEf)

---

Check the value's type in your select filter:

```
map(select(type == "object" and .b == 2))
```

[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#type), [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/8yGLIptSVP)

---

Filter out non-objects:

```
map(objects | select(.b == 2))
```

[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars), [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/fTBjKglkGJ)

Answer (score 2):

Just as [@hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67624350/5625547) suggested, use a `?` to skip entries that doesn't have a `.b`.

---

As of the second question, I'd use [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example21) so the result is an array as requested:

```
map(select(.b? == 2))
```

```json
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

#### [Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/7WadUwNDEf)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `?`: `.[]| select(.b? == 2)`.

From the docs:

> #### Optional Object Identifier-Index: `.foo?`
>
> Just like `.foo`, but does not output even an error when `.` is not an array or an object.